# Calling a script from popup widow to iframe on parent

Tags: javascript, iframe, popup

I have three pages that I am trying to tie together. The first parent page has an iframe page on it. This iframed page has a button that calls a popup window.

The popup window runs a jquery script, and upon success it needs to call a script on the iframe page.

IFRAME.HTML has this function

```
getDataReturn();
```

PARENT.HTML has the iframe

```
 <iframe id="presto-frame" src="iframe.html"></iframe>
```

POPUP.HTML has the script

```
 var frames = window.opener.parent.frames;
 alert(frames.length);
 var frame = window.opener.parent['presto-frame'];
 frame.getDataReturn($var1, $var2);
```

The popup console returns this:

```
TypeError: frame.getDataReturn is not a function
```

The alert returns 1. I have looked for several different solutions, and this is bit and pieces of several I have found.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the long way:

```
window.opener.getDataReturn();
```

should work, if `getDataReturn()` is global and both pages are in the same domain.

Comment: If I try window.opener.getDataReturn() I get 'Error: Permission denied to access property 'getDataReturn'. 

I tried window.opener.parent.getDataReturn() i get 'TypeError: window.opener.parent.getDataReturn is not a function'.

I am wondering if the function is not being found on the parent page.

Comment: Please, edit your comment, there's something missing

Comment: I reread my comment, not sure what is missing. I tried two methods and got two different error messages. Both pages are on the same domain.